# How do I pass data from one form builder to another?

Tags: 7, forms

I have a page callback that does this:

```
// ...
$page['search'] = drupal_get_form('search_form');
// ...
$page['list'] = drupal_get_form('list_form');
// ...
return $page;
```

The first form builds a search box where the user can enter a term that influences which rows should be presented in the following table. (which is also a form, but that doesn't necessarily matter, right?)

How can I get at the values in `$page['search']`? Could I construct a form alteration hook? Should I use a different approach altogether in my page callback?

Coming from a Java world, I would be inclined to have an object that has its internal state manipulated by the first call, and the second call using that info for its own output. I'm not sure how Drupal ties this together.

Comment: What you want to do? Are you looking to populate searched content in the list form?

Comment: @ShuaibNawaz - The list is populated from a database query, the search form adds a filter to that query.

Comment: Why are you doing it with two forms? I think you can do it on single. Are you expecting to populate filtered records over ajax call?

Comment: @ShuaibNawaz - It's two different operations. One is a search, one is a data submission. Different validation, different actions on submit. I don't want to put both in the same function. Of course I could, but I don't think it would be nice code.